# Lottie designs height and width is not working as per style

Tags: react-native, animation, lottie

I am using lottie designs and using the `style` attribute in this, the problem is when I am setting the `width` it also changes its `height`.

```
<LottieView 
    style={{width:200}
    source={require('../../../assests/lottie/test.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
/>
```

Please let me know how can I wrap it in a fixed height and width.

Answer (score 5):

We can set the height and width in the Lottie Component as we set the style in the View Component.

we simply can set height or width in Lottie component as below:

```
<LottieView 
    style={{ height: 200 }}
    source={require('../../../assests/lottie/test.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
/>
```

for more details check out the official docs:

https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native

Comment: it is not working as you will increase width of the lottie-View it's height will also change with width.

Comment: @PuneetKansal Yes, it will manage the height or width with the aspect ratio you only have to provide the height or width one of them.

Comment: but i don't want to maintain aspect ratio. So is there any way to discard aspect ratio.

Comment: @PuneetKansal Have a try by putting the Lottie Component in the view component and give the style to the view component and make the resizeMode="cover" of the Lottie Component

Answer (score 1):

```
                            ---React Native Solution----
```

Something that worked for me was using a View wrap around Lottie Component and also scaling it using the transform property to remove the padding.

```
<View style={styles().lottie}>
    <Lottie
      style={[
        {
          transform: [{scale: 1.8}],
        },
      ]}
      source={require('../../../assets/lottie/heartbeat-loading.json')}
      autoPlay
      loop
      resizeMode="cover"
    />
  </View> 

const styles = () =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    lottie: {
      width: dimensions.Width / 5,
      height: dimensions.Width / 5,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the width property of a LottieView using the style prop, the height of the animation is automatically adjusted to maintain its aspect ratio.

To wrap the LottieView in a fixed height and width, you can wrap it in a View container.

```js
<View style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}>
  <LottieView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    source={require('../../../assests/lottie/test.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
  />
</View>
```